# C#: System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart Set Line Size

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

This is probably a really simple question but I am having a lot of trouble trying to figure out which property sets the line size on the [**Chart**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.aspx) or [**Series**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.series.aspx) class. The line is really narrow and hard to see.

How do I set the **line size** for my **FastLine** chart?

```
Series set1 = new Series();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
     set1.Points.addY(x);
}
set1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
set1.Color = Color.Green;
chart1.Series.Add(set1);
chart1.Invalidate();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use **Borderwidth** and **BorderStyle**.

```
Series set1 = new Series();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
     set1.Points.addY(x);
}
set1.BorderWidth = 10;
set1.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
set1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
set1.Color = Color.Green;
chart1.Series.Add(set1);
chart1.Invalidate();
```

Border seems like a strange keyword for line width, but if you consider there are many types of graphs, not just fast line, it makes sense.